# Allocate list of views accessed in last 12 months

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Is it possible to list the clearcase views accessed in the last 12 months only? In a particular server, I want to list only the views accessed in a 12 months period. Since I am decommissioning this server, I want to keep the records of these view. Is it possible?

Any inputs are appreciated !!

Answer (score 1):

Considering [`cleartool lsview`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsview.htm), yo can use the `-age` option:

> Reports when and by whom the view was last accessed. Because view access events are updated only every 60 seconds, lsview may not report all recent events.

[This technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21289326) describes precisely what event will modify the "Last access" date of a view.

> **Only operations that result in a view database change will change this "last accessed" time**.
> These actions include:

- Writing a view private object
- Removing a view private file
- Checking out a file (which creates a view-private copy of the checked-out version)
- Checking in a file (which removes the view-private copy)
- Creating a view
- Write or create a derived object
- Wink-in a derived object
- Promote a derived object
- Set a config spec

> Actions such as starting the view, cd'ing in to a view, and setting to a view do not change the view configuration or database, and, thus, do not update the last accessed time.
>
> Additionally, since ClearCase caches RPC results to improve performance, subsequent executions of cleartool lsview -age may not immediately reflect the most recent operation that changed the above "last accessed" time. The "last accessed" change may take up to 5 minutes to be reflected in the command's output.
>
> **If the "last accessed" is to be used in a script to delete views over a certain age, please note that this implementation issue may cause views that are in fact in use to be eligible for removal**.
> One example is a view that is created to hold trigger scripts that are under source control. This view's configuration may never change, and it may not be used for actual modifications to the trigger scripts. Any such views would have to be specifically excluded from removal.